# Автодобавление партиций в секционированную по списку таблицу для новых ключей

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Имеется секционированная по списку таблица с ключём из поля `code`:

```
create table pltab (
    id number, code varchar2 (8), name varchar2 (32)
)
partition by list (code) (
    partition part_aa values ('AA', 'aa'),
    partition part_bb values ('BB', 'bb'),
    partition part_def values (default) 
)
;
```

Вставка уже известных ключей не вызывает проблем. Но всё чаше данные поступают с новыми ключами, например:

```
insert into pltab values (3, 'CC', 'item of CC');
```

и оказываются в партиции по-умолчанию. После этого, приходится вручную отделять записи с новыми ключами в новые партиции:

```
alter table pltab split partition part_def values ('CC') into (
    partition part_cc, partition part_def
);
```

Как реализовать автоматическое добавление новой партиции при вставке с новым  ключом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого случая есть автоматическое секционирование таблицы по листу
(см. [*automatic list-partitioned table*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6)):

```
create table ptab (
    id number, code varchar2 (8), name varchar2 (32)
)
partition by list (code) automatic (
    partition partdef values ('undef', 'unknown', 'none', null)
);
```

С предикатом `AUTOMATIC` нельзя создать партицию по-умолчанию (с ключом `default`). Вместо неё, добавте партицию со списком ключей, для которых заведомо не должна быть создана новая партиция.

При вставке:

```
insert into pltab 
   select rownum, column_value, 'item of '||column_value 
   from xmlTable ('"AA", "BB", "CC", "none", "unknown"')
;
```

будут автоматически созданы новые партиции с генерироавнными именами `SYS_Pnnnn`:

```
select partition_name, high_value, num_rows
from user_tab_partitions
where table_name = upper ('pltab') 
;

PARTITION_NAME   HIGH_VALUE           NUM_ROWS
---------------- ------------------ ----------
PARTDEF          'undef', 'unknown'          2
                 , 'none', null               

SYS_P2088        'AA'                        1
SYS_P2089        'BB'                        1
SYS_P2090        'CC'                        1
```

PS для уже существующих секционированных таблиц без партиции с ключом `default`, возможно их изменение без пересоздания, см. [*alter_automatic_partitioning*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877).

Comment: Поздравляю с новым достижением 10.000!